# How does Liz Cheney's losing the Republican primary impact the future of the GOP?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, republican-party, republican-primary

Liz Cheney has lost the Republican primaries. As I know, she represents a group of Republicans who criticized Trump. What does this loss mean for the GOP?

Comment: I would close the question but only on the ground that it's too broad. The "future of a political party" can mean a lot of things. If you say: "GOP's electoral odd in 2024 presidential election" that would be slightly better. Narrower questions are easier to answer.

Comment: This Q is being discussed on meta: https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6339/what-does-opinion-based-exactly-mean-in-this-community

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Liz Cheney's primary loss isn't that consequential in and of itself. Cheney's House seat was in trouble from the first moment she challenged Trump, and the Right-nationalist slide of the GOP will continue with or without her opposition in the House. Cheney's loss is a symptom of an ongoing process, not a cause of anything in itself.

The pertinent question is what Cheney does next. I don't know if she has the capacity to pull the GOP back towards center, but she has enough clout to fracture the party, and that could have consequences for 2024. We'll have to see what she does for the remainder of the year with no nagging worries about reelection.

Comment: I would never call Liz Cheney a centrist. While she certainly has become an anti-Trumper, that does not mean she is a centrist.

Comment: @DavidHammen: In objective terms you're correct, but by the standards of Trumpism *Dick* Cheney is a centrist. Liz is now well left of the Trump-core norm, so she is in fact a centralizing influence on the party. God have mercy on us all...

Comment: @user13229973: DIck Cheney is a neoconservative. I'm not sure I'd apply that label to Liz Cheney, who seems far less jingoistic than her father. Trump is a different beast entirely: an aspiring strong-man dictator riding a wave of white ethno/christian nationalism that he neither started nor subscribes to, but merely uses for his own purposes. One can be closer to the center without being on the opposite side of the spectrum; that's the essence of a spectrum.

Comment: What kind of would that "ongoing process" be?
The only process I see, is Trump cleaning republicans from "RINOs".

Comment: @SamGinrich: Conservatives have been moving towards a nationalist orientation since the end of the Clinton era. It began with Karl Rove's rage/grievance-centered neoconservative political strategy and the introduction of FOX News as a propaganda arm, began morphing into Christian nationalism via islamophobic messaging after 9/11, picked up a distinct white nationalist character after the election of Obama (the Tea Party), and fell into crazed conspiracy crap in the lead-up to Trump's election.

Comment: @SamGinrich: Trump was at best a minor influencer until the 2008 presidential election (when he caught some swell with the whole 'birther' thing). After that, he was the only candidate willing to play up to white and Christian nationalists, using the nationalist-typcial combination of victimization and violence rhetoric. There's no indication he believes any of that nonsense; he believes (and has shown) that he can manipulate that nonsense effectively for his own benefit.

Comment: Thank you for an exhaustive answer! Think, what you call neo-conservatism  is only a shadow of the anti-communism, that the US had in the 50s and was the main pilar of the cold war. Now, it's Putin, who constitutes, that the Western culture of Judeo-Christian values was under attack by destructive ideologies. The role of Trump is unclear to me, as even Alex Jones showed up on the serious outlet CNN to turn his back on Trump for advertising Fauci's Cv' policy, destructive in only his eyes.

Comment: ... read only a small section from Trump's books, where he claims, that low energy prices were essential for a functioning welfare state, as they multiply in each production step of a product.